# json and jsonschema tag vs json and schema tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We have been discussing [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601588/how-to-validate-that-json-object-fields-are-equal-with-nodejs-tv4-validation-lib#comment43749183_27601588) related to the construction of a [json schema](http://json-schema.org/) about which tags are more appropiate:

- json, schema
- json, jsonschema

As a general rule it seems a good idea to use the most defining tag (ie, jsonschema instead of schema) and avoid too general tags (schema).

In order to avoid an endless discussion in the post I request your opinion here.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358058/create-a-schema-for-its-destruction

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think that [schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema) is a good tag.  It's overly broad, since schemas are such a big concept.  I don't think anyone's an expert in schemas, not related to any specific technology.

So I'd go with [jsonschema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema), since that's the specific technology being discussed.

However, I don't actually know what jsonschema is, so maybe this opinion makes no sense.

Answer (score 10):

The [jsonschema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema) tag is more appropriate. The [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json)+[schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema) tags just means schemas for JSON in general, while the [jsonschema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema) tag refers to a well-defined specification.