# Is the schema tag useful and should it be deleted?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

After reading [json and jsonschema tag vs json and schema tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281219/json-and-jsonschema-tag-vs-json-and-schema-tags?cb=1), I question if the [schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema) tag is useful.

To quote for one of the answers.

> I don't think that schema is a good tag. It's overly broad, since
>   schemas are such a big concept. I don't think anyone's an expert in
>   schemas, not related to any specific technology.

Comment: The concept itself needs a tag IMO - but the question is do we want a single general tag that is further constrained by the presence of other tags, or dozens of more specific tags?