# Create a [schema] for its destruction

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I encountered [schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema) today. Its excerpt is exceptionally vague and already suggest the use of other tags:

> Schema means shape, or more generally, plan. It may be XML schema or Database schema.

The tag wiki then continues with two sections, without even a common header, for both XML-schema and Database-schema.
Both [xml-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-schema) and [database-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-schema) already exist, probably for use on their respective schemas.

So why does [schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema) exist? Is there a third option for its use, or is it just a general term which is better split between the two existing tags?

---

Of the 4882 questions in [schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema) just 661 are tagged [xml-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-schema) (or rather its synonym [xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xsd)) as well, and only 104 are also tagged [database-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-schema).

Note that I'm not asking for the tag to be removed ruthlessly, per se, but rather for an explanation as to why this tag might be useful to exist alongside the two specifics mentioned in the tag wiki. The community can then decide whether there is no use for it besides the existing tags, and thus can be burninated, or there is a use and the wiki can be rewritten to reflect that use, along with going through the questions to retag where necessary.

Comment: Would people downvoting this post please explain why they don't agree? I presume it's because they are opposed to burninating it, which I'd love good arguments against as an aswer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this disambiguation. A general schema is just a plan (as the tag says), and questions about planning, even for planning programs or projects or algorithms, are too broad and too opinion-based for Stack Overflow. So the general tag of [schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schema) is right out.

As for whether there are other specific uses of schema, like [xml-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-schema) or [database-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-schema), I know there is also [jsonschema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema), but I don't know about any additional cases. I think as we go along with the disambiguation, we should be able to point out any additional, unique subjects that call for schema tag.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281220/5211833), on a related question about [JSON] [schema] basically says the exact same thing: *It's overly broad, since schemas are such a big concept. I don't think anyone's an expert in schemas*